# Can't sort table with associative indexes

Tags: sorting, indexing, lua, associative-array, lua-table

Why I can't use table.sort to sort tables with associative indexes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only sort tables with consecutive integer keys starting at 1, i.e., lists.  If you have another table of key-value pairs,  you can make a list of pairs and sort that:

```
function sortpairs(t, lt)
  local u = { }
  for k, v in pairs(t) do table.insert(u, { key = k, value = v }) end
  table.sort(u, lt)
  return u
end
```

Of course this is useful only if you provide a custom ordering (`lt`) which expects as arguments key/value pairs.

This issue is discussed at greater length in a [related question about sorting Lua tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038418/associatively-sorting-a-table-by-value-in-lua).

Comment: So you both are saying there's no way to sort a table with custom (ie string) keys??? I really liked Lua, for being such flexibile language, but even crappy Java or (the best lang. ever) C# can do this.

Comment: Lua tables with string keys are *not* ordered.  If you want to order a set of key-value pairs, you change the representation.

Comment: But then I'm unable to get an item from it, because I have to save integer index of entry in table. And that index is going to change after deleting an entry...

Comment: @mnn: Since `table.sort` is not the solution, maybe you can post the actual programming problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I need to sort table by date time values it contains. But it doesn't contain only those values, it also has other essential info to be useful.

Answer (score 6):

In general, Lua tables are pure associative arrays. There is no "natural" order other than the as a side effect of the particular hash table implementation used in the Lua core. This makes sense because values of any Lua data type (other than `nil`) can be used as both keys and values; but only strings and numbers have any kind of sensible ordering, and then only between values of like type.

For example, what should the sorted order of this table be:

```
unsortable = {
    answer=42,
    true="Beauty",
    [function() return 17 end] = function() return 42 end,
    [math.pi] = "pi",
    [ {} ] = {},
    12, 11, 10, 9, 8
}
```

It has one string key, one boolean key, one function key, one non-integral key, one table key, and five integer keys. Should the function sort ahead of the string? How do you compare the string to a number? Where should the table sort? And what about `userdata` and `thread` values which don't happen to appear in this table?

By convention, values indexed by sequential integers beginning with 1 are commonly used as lists. Several functions and common idioms follow this convention, and `table.sort` is one example. Functions that operate over lists usually ignore any values stored at keys that are not part of the list. Again, `table.sort` is an example: it sorts only those elements that are stored at keys that are part of the list.

Another example is the `#` operator. For the above table, `#unsortable` is 5 because `unsortable[5] ~= nil` and `unsortable[6] == nil`. Notice that the value stored at the numeric index `math.pi` is not counted even though pi is between 3 and 4 because it is not an integer. Furthermore, none of the other non-integer keys are counted either. This means that a simple for loop can iterate over the entire list:

```
for i in 1,#unsortable do
    print(i,unsortable[i])
end
```

Although that is often written as

```
for i,v in ipairs(unsortable) do
    print(i,v)
end
```

In short, Lua tables are unordered collections of values, each indexed by a key; but there is a special convention for sequential integer keys beginning at 1.

**Edit:** For the special case of non-integral keys with a suitable partial ordering, there is a work-around involving a separate index table. The described content of tables keyed by string values is a suitable example for this trick.

First, collect the keys in a new table, in the form of a list. That is, make a table indexed by consecutive integers beginning at 1 with keys as values and sort that. Then, use that index to iterate over the original table in the desired order.

For example, here is `foreachinorder()`, which uses this technique to iterate over all values of a table, calling a function for each key/value pair, in an order determined by a comparison function.

```
function foreachinorder(t, f, cmp)
    -- first extract a list of the keys from t
    local keys = {}
    for k,_ in pairs(t) do
        keys[#keys+1] = k
    end
    -- sort the keys according to the function cmp. If cmp
    -- is omitted, table.sort() defaults to the < operator
    table.sort(keys,cmp)
    -- finally, loop over the keys in sorted order, and operate
    -- on elements of t
    for _,k in ipairs(keys) do
        f(k,t[k])
    end
end
```

It constructs an index, sorts it with [`table.sort()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-table.sort), then loops over each element in the sorted index and calls the function `f` for each one. The function `f` is passed the key and value. The sort order is determined by an optional comparison function which is passed to `table.sort`. It is called with two elements to compare (the keys to the table `t` in this case) and must return `true` if the first is less than the second. If omitted, `table.sort` uses the built-in `<` operator.

For example, given the following table:

```
t1 = {
    a = 1,
    b = 2,
    c = 3,
}
```

then `foreachinorder(t1,print)` prints:

```
a    1
b    2
c    3
```

and `foreachinorder(t1,print,function(a,b) return a>b end)` prints:

```
c    3
b    2
a    1
```

Comment: OK, how can I sort it then? After all I want to provide my own compare function, so I don't know why it can't be done. All table elements have the same pattern: key is a string and value is another table.

Answer (score 2):

Because they don't have any order in the first place.  It's like trying to sort a garbage bag full of bananas.

Comment: Actually, I think it's more like trying to sort a backpack full of apple cores