# Sort a Table[] in Lua

Tags: sorting, lua, lua-table

I have a Lua table that I am trying to sort. The table's format is as follows:

```
tableOfKills[PlayerName] = NumberOfKills
```

Which means, for example, if I had a player named Robin with a total of 8 kills and another named Jon with a total of 10 kills, the table would be:

```
tableOfKills[Robin] = 8
tableOfKills[Jon]   = 10
```

How would I sort that type of table to show the highest kills first? Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [copying data from table to antoher with order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153642/copying-data-from-table-to-antoher-with-order)

Comment: Table is not ordered array or something. It has no manifested order.

Answer (score 106):

A table in Lua is a set of key-value mappings with unique keys. The pairs are stored in arbitrary order and therefore the table is not sorted in any way.

What you can do is *iterate* over the table in some order. The basic `pairs` gives you no guarantee of the order in which the keys are visited. Here is a customized version of `pairs`, which I called `spairs` because it iterates over the table in a sorted order:

```
function spairs(t, order)
    -- collect the keys
    local keys = {}
    for k in pairs(t) do keys[#keys+1] = k end

    -- if order function given, sort by it by passing the table and keys a, b,
    -- otherwise just sort the keys 
    if order then
        table.sort(keys, function(a,b) return order(t, a, b) end)
    else
        table.sort(keys)
    end

    -- return the iterator function
    local i = 0
    return function()
        i = i + 1
        if keys[i] then
            return keys[i], t[keys[i]]
        end
    end
end
```

Here is an example of use of such function:

```
HighScore = { Robin = 8, Jon = 10, Max = 11 }

-- basic usage, just sort by the keys
for k,v in spairs(HighScore) do
    print(k,v)
end
--> Jon     10
--> Max     11
--> Robin   8

-- this uses an custom sorting function ordering by score descending
for k,v in spairs(HighScore, function(t,a,b) return t[b] < t[a] end) do
    print(k,v)
end
--> Max     11
--> Jon     10
--> Robin   8
```

Comment: +1 for an implementation of the `spairs()` iterator. Iterators are often a difficult concept to explain to new users, and well-explained examples in the wild will help mitigate that.

Answer (score -1):

An alternative way of sorting that avoids iterators and such is to pass the table to a list of key-value pairs (i.e.: list = {{k1,v1}, {k2, v2}, ...}.  Here's my solution:

```
local ranks = {}
for player,kills in pairs(tableOfKills) do
    table.insert(ranks, {player, kills})
end

-- Now we use Lua's built-in sort function with a short custom comparator function:
table.sort(ranks, function (a, b) return a[2] > b[2] end)

-- The only thing left to do is display the results:
for i=1,#ranks do
    print(ranks[i][1], ranks[i][2])
end
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).