# Sort two dimensional table after value

Tags: sorting, lua

I'm trying to make a function to sort a table after a value inside it. Is there no functions for this already in lua? I can't seem to find one.

```
local table2 = {};
for i, v in pairs(table) do
   if( table[i].field > table[i+1].field ) then
```

this is how far I got before I thought that it wouldn't work.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

The question is not quite clear, but if you mean to sort values in a table that may have some complex value, you can do this by using a "custom" search function:

```
local t = {
  {field = 2},
  {field = 1},
}
table.sort(t, function(t1, t2)
      return t1.field < t2.field
    end)
print(t[1].field, t[2].field) -- prints 1, 2
```

See [sorting table by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038418/associatively-sorting-a-table-by-value-in-lua) for related details.