# Iterate over table in order of value

Tags: sorting, lua, lua-table, computercraft

Lets say I have a table like so:

```
{
   value = 4
},
{
   value = 3
},
{
   value = 1
},
{
   value = 2
}
```

and I want to iterate over this and print the value in order so the output is like so:

```
1
2
3
4
```

How do I do this, I understand how to use `ipairs` and `pairs`, and `table.sort`, but that only works if using table.insert and the key is valid, I need to be loop over this in order of the value.

I tried a custom function but it simply printed them in the incorrect order.

I have tried:

- Creating an index and looping that
- Sorting the table (throws error: attempt to perform __lt on table and table)
- And a combination of sorts, indexes and other tables that not only didn't work, but also made it very complicated.

I am well and truly stumped.

Comment: Could you add some code so we could see what've you tried?

Comment: Sorry, I deleted it after I tried it (in my startup file) so not really... like I said it didn't work and it was just me stabbing in the dark. The majority of it was just loops, in loops... in loops

Comment: Have you read http://lua-users.org/wiki/SortedIteration examples? There you can find an example with iterating in order over table (its a little more complicated, but maybe this was what you meant?).

Comment: `table.sort(your_table, function(a,b) return a.value < b.value end)`

Comment: @deem I had seen this, although it was a little too complicated to follow. I might be wrong but all I could find were ways of sorting the keys, not the values.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I will test what you posted and let you know if it worked.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Thanks very much, this works perfectly. Now I must research how this works.

Thanks again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Associatively sorting a table by value in Lua](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038418/associatively-sorting-a-table-by-value-in-lua)

Comment: @harry "all I could find were ways of sorting the keys" You can't sort keys in Lua, ever. Entries in a Lua table actually have no defined ordering. The way you can iterate a table "in order" is to use sequential numeric keys (e.g. `t={'a','b','c'}`, which is short for `t={[1]='a',[2]='b',[3]='c'}`) then iterate using sequential numeric keys (e.g. `for i=1,#t do t[i]`, which is essentially what `ipairs` does internally). So "sorting" means looking at the *values* and moving them around so that when you iterate a table with sequential numeric keys, you get them back in the order you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort a Table\[\] in Lua](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706270/sort-a-table-in-lua)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Sorting the table

This was the right solution.

> (throws error: attempt to perform __lt on table and table)

Sounds like you tried to use `a < b`.

For Lua to be able to sort values, it has to know how to compare them. It knows how to compare numbers and strings, but by default it has idea how to compare two tables. Consider this:

```
local people = {
    { name = 'fred', age = 43 },
    { name = 'ted', age = 31 },
    { name = 'ned', age = 12 },
}
```

If I call `sort` on people, how can Lua know what I intend? I doesn't know what 'age' or 'name' means or which I'd want to use for comparison. I have to tell it.

It's possible to add a *metatable* to a table which tells Lua what the `<` operator means for a table, but you can also supply `sort` with a callback function that tells it how to compare two objects.

You supply `sort` with a function that receives two values and you return whether the first is "less than" the second, using your knowledge of the tables. In the case of your tables:

```
table.sort(t, function(a,b) return a.value < b.value end)

for i,entry in ipairs(t) do
    print(i,entry.value)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to leave the original table unchanged, you could create a custom 'sort by value' iterator like this:

```
local function valueSort(a,b)
    return a.value < b.value;
end

function sortByValue( tbl ) -- use as iterator
    -- build new table to sort
    local sorted = {};
    for i,v in ipairs( tbl ) do sorted[i] = v end;
    -- sort new table
    table.sort( sorted, valueSort );
    -- return iterator
    return ipairs( sorted );
end
```

When `sortByValue()` is called, it clones `tbl` to a new `sorted` table, and then sorts the sorted table. It then hands the `sorted` table over to `ipairs()`, and `ipairs` outputs the iterator to be used by the `for` loop.

To use:

```
for i,v in sortByValue( myTable ) do
  print(v)
end
```

While this ensures your original table remains unaltered, it has the downside that each time you do an iteration the iterator has to clone `myTable` to make a new `sorted` table, and then `table.sort` that `sorted` table.

If performance is vital, you can greatly speed things up by 'caching' the work done by the `sortByValue()` iterator. Updated code:

```
local resort, sorted = true;

local function valueSort(a,b)
    return a.value < b.value;
end

function sortByValue( tbl ) -- use as iterator
    if not sorted then -- rebuild sorted table
        sorted = {};
        for i,v in ipairs( tbl ) do sorted[i] = v end;
        resort = true;
    end
    if resort then -- sort the 'sorted' table
        table.sort( sorted, valueSort );
        resort = false;
    end
    -- return iterator
    return ipairs( sorted );
end
```

Each time you add or remove an element to/from `myTable` set `sorted = nil`. This lets the iterator know it needs to rebuild the `sorted` table (and also re-sort it).

Each time you update a `value` property within one of the nested tables, set `resort = true`. This lets the iterator know it has to do a `table.sort`.

Now, when you use the iterator, it will try and re-use the previous sorted results from the cached `sorted` table.

If it can't find the `sorted` table (eg. on first use of the iterator, or because you set `sorted = nil` to force a rebuild) it will rebuild it. If it sees it needs to resort (eg. on first use, or if the `sorted` table was rebuilt, or if you set `resort = true`) then it will resort the `sorted` table.