# What would be the best way to sort a table of tables by the second value of the tables and then return the first value?

Tags: lua

I want to sort the table i have here by the second value and then return the first string. what would be the best way to do this? apologies if my explanation is poor, i am very new to coding.

```
function ()
 t1 = {"Table1", 1011}
 t2 = {"Table2", 20222}
 t3 = {"Table3", 303333}
 t4 = {"Table4", 4044}
tTable = {t1, t2, t3, t4}
table.sort(tTable[tTable][2])
return tTable[#tTable][1]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Associatively sorting a table by value in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038418/associatively-sorting-a-table-by-value-in-lua)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's look what you're doing:

```
function ()
```

You need to put an `end` after the function body to avoid syntax errors.

Also on it's own this won't do anything useful as you're defining an anonymous function.
Unless you're assigning this to a value it will have no effect.

So you should do something like

`function myFunction() end` or `myFunction = function () end`

Then you create 4 global tables `t1`, `t2`, `t3`, `t4`.
You put them into another global table `tTable`.

You should use local variables wherever it is possible.

Then you try to sort a table in `table.sort(tTable[tTable][2])`

`tTable[tTable]` is `nil`. You never added a value to `tTable` for key `tTable`.
Hence `tTable[tTable][2]` will cause an error because you attempt to index a nil value.
Even if there was such thing it would probably not be a table which would then cause an error because `table.sort` expects a table.

`return tTable[#tTable][1]` will return the first element of the last element of `tTable` which is `tTable[4][1]` or `t4[1]` or `"Table4"`

Personally I would recommend that you learn more basics befor you attempt to sort tables.
To use tables you must know how to assign and get values to and from them. To get custom sorting you need to know how to define function. Both is not the case.

Now to the sorting problem:

Refer to the [Lua Reference Manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-table.sort)

There you'll learn that you can provide a function that tells Lua which of two elements comes first.

```
table.sort(tTable, function(a,b) return a[2] < b[2] end)
```

will sort `tTable` by the second value of its elements in ascending order.

```
local tTable = {
  {"Table1", 1011},
  {"Table2", 20222},
  {"Table3", 303333},
  {"Table4", 4044},
}
table.sort(tTable, function(a,b) return a[2] < b[2] end)
print(tTable[1][1])
```